# Передать данные из частичного представления в контроллер по кнопке

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc

На страничке Create использую частичное представление для динамического добавления текстбоксов. Вот реализация:

**Create.cshtml**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="3">Checks</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="tableCheck">
            @Html.Partial("_checklist")
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="button" value="Add check" id="addCheck" />
}
```

**Скрипт**

```
$(function () {
    $("#addCheck").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Checklists/GenerateChecks',
            data: $(this).closest("form").serialize(),
            success: function (html) {
                $('#tableCheck').html(html);
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**Ну и само частичное представление _checklist.cshtml**, где есть кнопки удаления для каждой вещи в списке. По кнопке я пытаюсь передать id вещи и саму модель в контроллер в метод DeleteCheck.

```
@model TestManagementTools.Models.Checklist

@if (Model != null) {
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Checks.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @(i + 1)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Checks[i].Value, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </td>
            <td>
                //пробуем передать
                <a href="@Url.Action("DeleteCheck", "Checklists", new { checklist = Model, id = Model.Checks[i].Id })" role="button">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }   
}
```

А вот, собственно, и методы в контроллере **ChecklistsController.cshtml**.

```
//добавление проверки по кнопке
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GenerateChecks(Checklist checklist)
{
    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        Check check = new Check();

        if (checklist.Checks == null)
        {
            checklist.Checks = new List<Check>();
        }

        checklist.Checks.Add(check);

        return PartialView("_checklist", checklist);
    }
    return PartialView("_checklist", checklist);
}

//удаление проверки, но сюда приходит модель равная null
public ActionResult DeleteCheck(int id, Checklist checklist)
{
    checklist.Checks.RemoveAt(id);
    return PartialView("_checklist", checklist);
}
```

Так вот вопрос, как передать из моего частичного представления id вещи и модель в контроллер? Сейчас, как написано выше, приходит null

Comment: Судя по вашей разметке, у вас на странице нигде нет формы, соответственно, данным неоткуда сериализоваться.

Comment: Вы про страницу Create? Излишне упростил код для форума, уже исправил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a class="link-delete" href="#" role="button" data-checkid="@Model.Checks[i].Id">Delete</a>

$("#tableCheck").on("click", ".link-delete", function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "@Url.Action("DeleteCheck", "Checklists")" + "?id=" + $(this).data("checkid"),
        data: $(this).closest("form").serialize(),
        success: function (html) {
            $('#tableCheck').html(html);
        },
        error: function (msg) {
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59440/discussion-on-answer-by-igor-------).